# Как вырубить экранную клавиатуру виндовс 10?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Я запускаю свою клавиатуру qtvirtualkeyboard и она открывается поверх обычной на планшете...

Зачем я добавил ее? а потому что приложение в полноэкранном режиме)) ( ф11 ) поверх стандартной клавиатуры => не видать что набираешь...

Можно поставить галочку не показывать клавиатуру вообще... но это тоже не выход.
Можно ли как то программно отключить или включить системную клавиатуру, чтобы твое приложение работало только со своей клавиатурой?
Windows 10 / surface pro

upd

Comment: Видимо у вас что-то не так с полноэкранностью. Оно не должно мешать использованию стандартной экранной клавиатуры.

Comment: Программно запрограммированная кнопка для фуллскрина

Comment: Нет, фуллскрин не отключает системную клавиатуру на серфейса , а делает ее только "ЗА" приложением так, что ее не видно, но она нажимается

Comment: Видимо у вас что-то не так с полноэкранностью. Оно не должно мешать использованию стандартной экранной клавиатуры.